# Index of last occurrence of max before min

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

The title might not be intuitive--let me provide an example.  Say I have `df`, created with:

```
a = np.array([[ 1. ,  0.9,  1. ],
              [ 0.9,  0.9,  1. ],
              [ 0.8,  1. ,  0.5],
              [ 1. ,  0.3,  0.2],
              [ 1. ,  0.2,  0.1],
              [ 0.9,  1. ,  1. ],
              [ 1. ,  0.9,  1. ],
              [ 0.6,  0.9,  0.7],
              [ 1. ,  0.9,  0.8],
              [ 1. ,  0.8,  0.9]])

idx = pd.date_range('2017', periods=a.shape[0])
df = pd.DataFrame(a, index=idx, columns=list('abc'))
```

I can get the index location of each respective column minimum with

```
df.idxmin()
```

Now, **how could I get the location of the last occurrence of the column-wise maximum, *up to* the location of the minimum?**

Visually, I want to find the location of the green max's below:

[image]

where the max's after the minimum occurrence are ignored.

**I can do this with `.apply`, but can it be done with a mask/advanced indexing?**

Desired result:

```
a   2017-01-07
b   2017-01-03
c   2017-01-02
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Clarification: if a column goes `1 0 2`, do you want the index of the 1, ignoring the 2?

Comment: Is your index sorted?

Comment: And what if you have repeated min?

Comment: Yes @user2357112.  So first find the min, mask all values occurring after that min, then find the last occurrence of max in that masked frame

Comment: @Dark let's assume for simplicity there are no repeated mins

Comment: Index is sorted @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: @BradSolomon Actually, now that I've gotten rid of the apply, it doesn't matter. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apply a `mask` and then call `idxmax` on the reversed dataframe.

```
df.mask((df == df.min()).cumsum().astype(bool))[::-1].idxmax()

a   2017-01-07
b   2017-01-03
c   2017-01-02
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

**Details**

First, identify the location of the smallest items per column.

```
df.min()

a    0.6
b    0.2
c    0.1
dtype: float64

i = df == df.min()
i

                a      b      c
2017-01-01  False  False  False
2017-01-02  False  False  False
2017-01-03  False  False  False
2017-01-04  False  False  False
2017-01-05  False   True   True
2017-01-06  False  False  False
2017-01-07  False  False  False
2017-01-08   True  False  False
2017-01-09  False  False  False
2017-01-10  False  False  False
```

Now, mask those values and beyond!

```
j = df.mask(i).cumsum().astype(bool))
j

              a    b    c
2017-01-01  1.0  0.9  1.0
2017-01-02  0.9  0.9  1.0
2017-01-03  0.8  1.0  0.5
2017-01-04  1.0  0.3  0.2
2017-01-05  1.0  NaN  NaN
2017-01-06  0.9  NaN  NaN
2017-01-07  1.0  NaN  NaN
2017-01-08  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-01-09  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-01-10  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

To find the last maximum, just reverse and call `idxmax`.

```
j[::-1].idxmax()

a   2017-01-07
b   2017-01-03
c   2017-01-02
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `masking` -

```
>>> a = df.values
>>> mask = a.argmin(0) > np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]
>>> idx = a.shape[0] - (a*mask)[::-1].argmax(0) - 1
>>> df.index[idx]
DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-07', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Here's another `masking` based one that sets the invalid ones in each col to `NaN` and then makes use of `np.nanargmax` -

```
a = df.values
min_idx = a.argmin(0)
mask = min_idx < np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]
a[mask] = np.nan
idx = a.shape[0]-np.nanargmax(a[::-1],axis=0) - 1
out = df.index[idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `last_valid_index`

```
df[df==df.min()]=0

(df.mask((df.cumprod()==0)|(df!=df.max()))).apply(lambda x : x.last_valid_index())
Out[583]:
a   2017-01-07
b   2017-01-03
c   2017-01-02
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```